# Writing script that logs in and out of ssh server

Tags: shell-script

For the sake of this explanation, *machine* is my laptop, and I use it to connect to a remote server - which I will refer to as *server_name*.

The procedure can be described as follows:

1. I connect to server *server_name* with `ssh` from *machine*
2. I then inserts password for *server_name*
3. I compile something on *server_name*
4. I log out of *server_name* (using `exit`)
5. I then reboot *server_name* from *machine*
6. I `ping` *server_name* and then I wait until I get a response from it (`ping`'s output is shown on the console)
7. I `ssh` into *server_name* again
8. I run some checks
9. Finally, I `exit` to *server_name* in order to go back to *machine*

To accomplish the above recipe, I **manually** run the following commands from *machine*:

```
<machine>$ ssh server_name
insert password for server_name:
<server_name>$ cd /some/path/
<server_name>$ make clean > /dev/null
<server_name>$ make > /dev/null
<server_name>$ exit
<machine>$ ./my_reboot_script server_name
<machine>$ ping server_name
PING 10.23.22.7 with 56(84) bytes of data.
ping output... (not very interesting)...
ping output... (not very interesting)...
ping output... (not very interesting)...
ping output... (not very interesting)...
^C
<machine>$ ssh server_name
insert password for server_name:
<server_name>$ ./run_some_checks
<server_name>$ exit
<machine>$ echo "Done!"
```

Couple of notes on the above is in order:
- `my_reboot_script` is just a program that allows me to cold-reboot *server_name* from the comport of my own seat.
- After I cold-reboot *server_name*, I need to wait for it to go back up, so I can reconnect to it using `ssh`. To do that, I use `ping`; it is merely used as an indication to when *server_name* is ready to accept connections again; Only when I see the `ping` output finally spawning on the console, I interrupt it with Ctrl+C, and then I `ssh` into *server_name*.

Doing the above manually is tedious and time consuming.
So I want to automate the above process, but there are three difficulties:

1. While connected to *server_name*, issuing the `exit` command from the shell gracefully logs me out and returns me to *machine*. However, issuing `exit` from within a script `.sh` file will terminate the script...
2. How can I automate the password to *server_name* phase? I don't want to manually typing the password, but rather let the script do it; in other words - I want to somehow hardcode the password into the script so it won't bother me with it.
3. The "waiting-for-server-to-be-ready-for-ssh-connections" phase: How can I automate this? Meaning, instead of just `ping`ing until I get a response, then interrupting with Ctrl+C, I want the script to `ping`, recognize that there is a response from *server_name*, then connect with `ssh`. Although, using `ping` might not be such a good idea here, since response to `ping` does not guarantee that *server_name* is ready to listen to `ssh` connections (from my experience with the above process, it takes a few more seconds from the moment the first response to the `ping` is obtained). Therefore, a better approach might be for the script to keep on trying to `ssh` in a loop until it granted access (some sort of a busy waiting mechanism, or even a loop that sleeps and wakes up every few seconds to try to connect).

Comment: regarding 2. - why not use key based authentication?

Answer (score 3):

If you can get the public key data from your machine to the server's `.ssh/authorized_key` files, you could run the compilation with a single `ssh` invocation per server, without ever entering a password:

```
ssh someone@$SERVER 'cd /some/path/; make clean > /dev/null; make > /dev/null;'
```

You could put that in a loop in a shell script, changing the value of shell variable `SERVER` each time through. If you don't mind entering your password for every `ssh` invocation, you don't even need the public key data on the servers.

Comment: Hey Bruce Ediger, thanks for your answer. Appreciate it.
Your elegant suggestion does solve 1. and 2. in my post, but this still doesn't solve 3. Do you have an idea on how to automate 3?